# Wordpress Redirects Pages to a weird permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have a Wordpress website it started acting weird.
When ever any page from menu is clicked like `domain.com/about-us` it gets redirected to `domain.com/?q=%2Fabout-us%2F` and does not open page.

It stays on the same page.

a CURL -I returns this:
[image: CURL]

So i dont know where this redirect is setup. 
I have tried changing permalinks to `%postname%`.

I also know permalink only affect posts not pages but not sure.
There's no redirection plugin either there.

I need someone to help me finding the issue.

Comment: I've found a similar support thread, try sejiro's solution in templates/features.php - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ugly-internal-links-q/

Comment: still it does not help since im not using AMP, what about using htaccess?